# How to redirect from old branch to new branch documentation at ReadTheDocs?

Tags: redirect, read-the-docs

We are rendering ReadTheDocs (RTD) documentation for a software project hosted at github (in particular, [this one](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion)).

Recently we have changed our main branch due to internal policies. In the past we used "develop" as main branch. Now, we are unsing "master" as default branch. The "develop" branch is still in our repository, but it is not receiving new contributions (at the end, it will be deleted).

The problem is that all the links to documentation (that we have been distributing among our users during years) like this one https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html will point to an obsolete piece of documentation, as now the right one is https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html

Does RTD have some functionality (redirect, alias, etc.) that could solve this problem? As far as I checked, RTD supports several redirection types ("Prefix redirect", "Page redirect", etc.) but after looking them all it seems they cannot do this kind of redirection (or I haven't understood how the work to do it :). I mean redirecting

```
https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/$lang/develop/path/to/something.html
```

to

```
https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/$lang/master/path/to/something.html
```

Any idea about how to solve this problem or feasible workarounds will be highly appreciated.